# acid-state convenience wrapper without template haskell?

Tags: haskell, acid-state

In [`acid-state` tutorial](http://www.happstack.com/docs/crashcourse/AcidState.html#acid_state) all the examples use Template Haskell. However, due to [some reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857030/whats-so-bad-about-template-haskell) I am not very keen on using it.

I know one can use acid-state without template haskell, as shown here:
http://mirror.seize.it/acid-state/examples/HelloWorldNoTH.hs

but I am wandering if there are any convenience wrappers or libraries to help make use of acid-state easier (without the use of template haskell)?

P.S.: My purpose is to implement a database layer for a web-app.

Comment: In this case, the TH *is* the convenience wrapper you're looking for.  I'm typically on the side of limiting use of Template Haskell (as are the Happstack guys afaik), but this a very safe and appropriate use of it IMO.

Comment: It's just there is no predefined syntax when it comes to TH - and all those `''` just look weird and hard to read (with magical uppercase variants appearing everywhere).

Comment: There is predefined syntax for this use of TH.  Quasiquotes are where you don't have predefined syntax, but there are no quasiquotes here.

Answer (score 4):

You can't write a function that derives an instance for something, that's why Acid-State makes use of Template Haskell.

The developers of Acid-State have mentioned before that they wouldn't need to use TH if GHC added support for automatically deriving classes (much like `data SomeData = Foo | Bar deriving (Show)`)

Many of the points listed *against* TH in the post you linked only apply under specific circumstances (for example, you can be pretty sure that Acid-State's TH functions won't launch any missiles)

I really don't think you should worry too much about using TH - it can be helpful sometimes!

Comment: Thanks. sorry for the dumb question but what does deriving classes do?

Comment: It adds an instance of a class automatically. In tazjin's example above, it means that you don't have to write `instance Show SomeData where showsPrec _ Foo = showString "Foo"; showsPrec _ Bar = showString "Bar"`; GHC will produce that instance automatically. It would be nice if you could also write `deriving (Acid)` or something similar.

Comment: Oh I see. Another dumb question: why can't this be enabled with language extensions i.e. those things in `{-# #-}`

Comment: It's possible with [Generics](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.2/html/users_guide/generic-programming.html) actually, but nobody has made an adapter for `acid-state` yet as far as I know. And using Generics is slower than using TH.