# How can I concisely represent a heterogenous sum type in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, algebraic-data-types, sum-type

I'm writing a program that transcodes financial statements into [a ledger](https://ledger-cli.org). In that program I have types representing different activities:

```hs
data Withdrawal = Withdrawal { wTarget :: !Text, wAmount :: !Cash, wBalance :: !Cash }
data Fee = { fFee :: !Cash, fBalance :: !Cash }
-- many more
```

I use those types, because I have functions that are transaction-type specific.

I also wanted to write an activity parser that translates CSV records into those types, so I created an `Activity` sum type:

```hs
data Activity =
  ActivityFee Fee
  | ActivityWithdrawal Withdrawal
  | -- ...

parseActivity :: CsvRecord -> Activity
```

That `Activity` is quite boilerplate'y. Having to have a new `Activity*` constructor for a new activity type is slightly cumbersome.

Is there a more idiomatic or better design pattern for this problem? Was it C++, `std::variant` would be convenient, because adding a new activity type wouldn't entail adding a new boilerplate constructor.

I've considered type-classes, but the problem with them is that they are not closed and I can't pattern match to create a function like `applyActivity :: Activity -> Wallet -> Wallet`. I see that I could make `applyActivity` into a function of an `Activity` class, but then problem is that this solution is only straightforward if only one argument is using this pattern. If we had two arguments like `foo :: (ClassOne a, ClassTwo b) => a -> b -> c`, then it's not clear to which class `foo` should belong.

Comment: You could try using [template haskell](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell) - it seems to be [looked down upon](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10857030/17592995) by the community but I don't see a downside to using it for this kind of boilerplate generation. You should be able to reduce the declaration of `Activity` to something like: `mkActivity [''Withdrawal, ''Fee,...]`. [This](https://www.parsonsmatt.org/2015/11/15/template_haskell.html) is a good tutorial

Comment: Other than template haskell as mentioned above, `Typeable` is probably the closest you can get to what you desire (runtime type checking). Making unions *tagged* is intentional by the design of Haskell and is the correct decision IMO. But I do get your point.

Comment: Personally, I like [pattern synonyms](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/exts/pattern_synonyms.html). One can write, e.g., `pattern K x y = K1 (K2 (K3 x y))` and then simply write `foo (K x y) = K (x+1) (y-1)` as if `K` were a constructor. You'll need to define your synonyms, so some boilerplate is still around (unless you automate it with Template Haskell). This won't reduce the boilerplate in defining the types, but that in using them later on.

Comment: If you have two arguments, use a two-argument typeclass. `foo :: ClassBoth a b => a -> b -> c`

Comment: So you basically want something like `Either`, but with support for an arbitrary number of choices instead of just two?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I'd say that's close to what I'm considering.

Answer (score 2):

One option is not bothering to define the sum type, and instead make `parseActivity` return the `Wallet -> Wallet` operation that characterizes activities, wrapped in some `Parser` type with an [`Alternative`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/GHC-Base.html#t:Alternative) instance.

```
parseActivity :: CsvRecord -> Parser (Wallet -> Wallet)
```

You would still need to define a big `Parser` value using a bunch of [`<|>`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/GHC-Base.html#v:-60--124--62-) that composed the `Parser`s for each possible activity.

Additional operations other than `Wallet -> Wallet`  could be supported by making the parser return a record of functions:

```
data ActivityOps = ActivityOps { 
        applyActivity :: Wallet -> Wallet,
        debugActivity :: String
    }
```

This is still not as versatile as the sum type, because it constrains beforehand the operations that we might do with the activity. To support a new operation, we would need to change the `Parser ActivityOps` value. With the sum type, we would simply define a new function.

A variant of this solution would be to define a typeclass like

```
class ActivityOps a where
    applyActivity :: a -> Wallet -> Wallet
    debugActivity :: a -> String
```

And make the `Parser` return some kind of existential like:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTSyntax #-}
data Activity where
    MakeActivity :: ActivityOps a => a -> Activity
```

This is sometimes [frowned upon](https://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/), but it would have the benefit of being able to easily invoke `ActivityOps` methods on activities of known type.

Comment: Related: the "return a command" trick. https://www.haskellforall.com/2021/10/the-return-command-trick.html

Answer (score 0):

[Extensible sums](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/summer-0.3.7.1) are a possible alternative. In that case one would write

```hs
type Activity = Sum '[Fee, Withdrawal]
```

and use `match (\fee -> ...) (\withdrawal -> ...)` as a substitute for pattern matching.